# Can't extract Data with For Loop (JavaScript / Fetch)

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Why can't I extract the fields that I want from the for loop? 
[Console Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9xoj.png)
[JSON Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zETuL.png)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      let user = 'example';
      fetch(`/jsonresponse/${user}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {

          // The line below works and prints the username
          console.log(data['UsersInfo'][0].username)

          // Doesn't work in a for Loop
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data['UsersInfo'][i].username);
          }
        });
```

Any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Did you mean to do `for (let i = 0; i < data['UsersInfo'].length; i++)` ?

Comment: @MauroAguilar Exactly why it's not working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in for loop you need to loop over `data["UsersInfo"]` not just `data`

```
                        vvvvvvvvvvvv
for (let i = 0; i < data["UsersInfo"].length; i++) {
  console.log(data["UsersInfo"][i].username);
}
```

it's better to store user `users` in array and loop over them with [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)

```
const users = data["UsersInfo"];
for (const user of users) {
  console.log(user.username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the tip!

Comment: Welcome and If my answer solved your question you can consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both myself and yourself as well. There is no obligation to do this!